# While generating a hash of a file using Python3's hashlib.blake2b , are these two methods functionally similar?

Tags: python, hashlib

I must use Python3.7 in the environment I find myself in. Common tutorials on how to utilize the hashlib.blake2b module show using a 'walrus' while reading out the chunks of the file to be hashed

Example of conventional approach:

```
def makeNormalHash():
    with open('fizzy.jpg', "rb") as f:
        file_hash = hashlib.blake2b()
        while chunk := f.read(8192):
            file_hash.update(chunk)
        hexdig = file_hash.hexdigest()
        dig = file_hash.digest()
        return hexdig,dig
```

This usage of the := operator has me a little confused but I have attempted to extrapolate out its end resulting functionality in this usecase but written for Python3.7 instead of Python3.8. My understanding of how := works yielded the following :

```
def makeDifferentHash():
    with open('fizzy.jpg', "rb") as f:
        foo_hash = hashlib.blake2b()
        chunk = f.read(8192)
        while len(chunk) > 0:
            foo_hash.update(chunk)
            chunk = f.read(8192)
        foohexdig = foo_hash.hexdigest()
        foodig = foo_hash.digest()
        return foohexdig, foodig
```

Which at first glance seems to work just the same but if I compare the resulting values when hashing the same file I come to find out that the values do not match.

```
nhd, nd = makeNormalHash()
fhd, fd = makeDifferentHash()

if(nhd != fhd):
    print('hexdig no match')
if(nd != fd):
    print('foodig no match')
```

I believe I should anticipate getting the same resulting values when hashing the same file in the same manner each time, this is to confirm the file is valid and/or not tampered with. So I am using the same method ( blake2b ) each time but I am changing how I am looping through the file. Is this the cause of the mismatch of digest values or am I missing another aspect of hashing that is creating this difference?

Ultimately I am trying to make a python3.7 friendly function that replaces the usage of the walrus operator ( := )

Any ideas?

*Walrus Operator == Assignment Expression PEP572

Comment: You're hashing two different files, of course the results are different.  (You have accurately translated the code to pre-3.8, although I'd personally write `while chunk:` instead of `while len(chunk) > 0:`.)

Comment: @jasonharper I forgot to change the file name, my mistake. In actual testing it is done with the same file. I will adjust the typo, thank you for pointing it out so I can be more clear! :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when the file is modified, it gets empty first. At that point the hash is the "empty string hash" which should be ignored.  You can declare the empty hash for the empty string (`b''`) like this:

```
tempHash = hashlib.blake2b()
tempHash.update(b'')
emptyHash = tempHash.hexdigest()
```